# Takes hours for the ethernet to start working(only 7 working wires)

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

I have an interesting problem. The situation is that I have a long ethernet cable and when i check the cable with my ethernet cable tester, it says that only seven of the eight wires works. I know it may look like the easiest way would just be to replace the cable.

But the interesting part is that, if I plug it into my windows-computer(Realtek PCI-e GBE family network card) it takes always some hours for it to start working, but eventually it starts working, I am really wondering how this is possible? Will ethernet work with one faulty cable? What could be the cause that it starts working after a very long time?

Every ideas will be helpful, just a point in the right direction. An other detail is that if I make any changes to the Ethernet card it stops working again for hours.

Answer (score 4):

100 Mbps Ethernet (aka Fast Ethernet) typically uses 100BASE-TX in the physical layer, which uses only 2 pairs. My guess would be after some time of unsuccessful attempts to communicate your devices fall back from Gigabit Ethernet to Fast Ethernet and successfully communicate over 2 functional pairs. Hard-setting both ends to use Fast Ethernet only would make them work instantly if my guess is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like you are completely correct, I changed to 10Mbps full duplex and now it is working like a charm. If i rearange the order of the wires in the cable, I am pretty certain that 100mps will start working aswell(atm that option does not work), but for me that is no big deal, I just want low and steady ping and does not need so high speeds

Comment: @Matt If my memory serves 10 Mbps Ethernet works over just one pair. Rearranging pairs may not work [reliably], they're not interchangeable - different pairs have different twist to minimize signal interference.